# How display Activity from Notification without display the Root Activity?

Tags: android

In my app I have a notification the has a "Dismiss" button, that performs a action.

This action starts with a confirmation dialog (a Yes/No dialog).

In order to do this, I have a Activity that uses a transparent theme and, when the activity starts, I display the dialog.

It works fine, the Activity is created when I click the Notification Action button then the Dialog is displayed, but... if the MainActivity of the app has been displayed previously and the user has closed it via the Home button instead of the Back button, the Application Main Activity is displayed behind my Dialog.

Is possible to solve this issue?

Transparent Activity definition:

```
<activity android:name=".AlertActionReceiverActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@style/AppThemeTransparent" />
```

Creation of the Notification Action Button

```
            device_notification.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_dismiss, getString(R.string.dismiss_alert).toUpperCase(), PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), getNotificationPendingIntentIdentifier(-1, 2), new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlertActionReceiverActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).setAction(AlertActionReceiverActivity.ACTION_DISMISS_ALERT).putExtra(AlertActionReceiverActivity.EXTRA_ALARM, active_alarm), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

[image: This occurs when the user clicks Home button in the Main Activity and a few minutes ago it clicks the Notification Action Button]

[image: This occurs when the user clicks Back button in the Main Activity and a few minutes ago it clicks the Notification Action Button or when the Main Activity hasn't been displayed previously, and is the desired behavior]

Comment: a possible way is to finish the activity in onPause()...

Comment: Yes, this is the easy solution. But I prefer a solution that don't needs it due to the Main Activity also can create child Activities.

Comment: indeed it is not possible to handle home button press and even if You find a way to do it, it should not be done. So that seems the only possible solution for me....The only alternative is to register a broadcastReceiver inside Your main Activity and send a broadcast from within the notification. Then the receiver receives that broadcast and You can finish Your mainactivity.....

Answer (score 0):

Like you said finishing the activity on the onPause() method is not good so for me i use a preference to know if the application main activity is opened or not and the following happens

```
if(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.APPLICATION_ON,false))
    {
        Log.e("Activity is in background","background");
        try
        {
            Intent bringToForeground=new Intent(context, Main_Activity.class);
            bringToForeground.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(bringToForeground);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Intent activate=new Intent(context,Main_Activity.class);
            activate.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(activate);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Activity is not in background",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You misunderstand. He doesn't want the mainactivity to be visible

Comment: Thanks, but I think your answer is forcing the Main Activity to be displayed, and I need the opposite. I need the Main Activity don't displayed when I display the dialog. Thanks!

Comment: @TheMatrix  May i know where is your dialog and what you are calling exactly when the dialog button is pressed so that we know more how to help?